# Overloading and overriding issue

Tags: c#, overriding, overloading

I want to override a method (`method(int x)`):

```
public class A 
{
    public virtual void method(int x)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("base");
    }
}

public class B : A
{
    public override void method(int x)     
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("overridden");
    }

    public void method(Double x)    
    {
        Console.WriteLine("overloaded");
    } 
}
```

and I'm calling it like so:

```
public static class Program  
{   
    public static void Main() 
    {
        B obj = new B();
        obj.method(1);
    } 
}
```

For some reason, "overloaded" is printed and not "overriden" as I expect. If I change `class B` to the following, the Main method now prints "overridden":

```
public class B
{
    public void method(int x)     
    { 
        Console.WriteLine("overridden");
    }

    public void method(Double x)    
    {
        Console.WriteLine("overloaded");
    } 
}
```

Why is this happening?
Does it because **Override** keyword?

Comment: overloading is writing the same method with different signature and overriding the is changing the behavior of the inherited method

Comment: I've added an [example](https://rextester.com/AKMTBZ25977) demonstrating how having the inheritance and override on the `void method(int x)` changes the behaviour..

Comment: @Op, do you want an explanation for the behavior, or a solution to it?

Comment: *"why is it like this?"* - I think the question was pretty clear.

Comment: @John just a small thing in the second print it should be "class c:" and not "class b"

Comment: it looks like when choosing an overload, if there are any compatible methods declared in a derived class, all signatures declared in the base class are ignored - even if they're overridden in the same derived class!

Answer (score 0):

You do not override the function, you are overloading it. If you cast the 1 to int, it should work.

Comment: This is a C# question, and method overrides don't work the way you describe.

Comment: @override is how you write override in java

Comment: then if i pass an int as param..why is it calling the method with double param

Comment: Oh wait now i see it :D john and styx are both correct, i changed my answer

Comment: @MasterOfDesaster i even type casted 1 to int and passed it..even then overloaded is printed

Comment: *If you cast the 1 to int, it should work.* NO it won't work

Comment: I Think casting is happining implicetly